# Geometry of the irrational torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, orbifolds, generalized-smooth-spaces, diffeology

One of the motivations of diffeology is to study singular spaces such as the irrational torus. The irrational torus $T_α$ of slope $α∈R∖Q $ as a diffeological space is given by the quotient space $ R/(Z+αZ)$, in Iglesias-Zemmour's book "diffeology", Exercise 4 p.8. It is proved that the irrational torus is not a manifold in Exercise 74 p.84. So my question is whether the irrational torus is an orbifold or not.

By an orbifold of dimension $n$, we mean a diffeological space which is locally diffeomorphic to $R^n/G$, for some finite subgroup $G⊂GL(R^n)$, and $R^n/G$ is equipped with the quotient diffeology.
 The group
$G$ may change from point to point.

Comment: It's not a Hausdorff space. Orbifolds are, by definition, Hausdorff.

Comment: @LeeMosher It could be a non-Hausdorff orbifold, just like people are sometimes interested in non-Hausdorff manifolds, no?

Comment: If you are happy to drop the Hausdorff axiom, there's plenty of other properties to disprove. The action of $Z + \alpha Z$ on $R$ is a free action, so the orbifold structure would actually be a manifold structure. And, as you say, it's not a manifold.

Comment: What if $T_α  $ is diffeomorphic to $R/G$ where $G$ is not acting freely?

Comment: I think in general, since the topology of $ T_α$  is trivial, it is not an orbifold (and particularly, it is not a manifold). Not because of non-Hausdorffness. Because otherwise the topology of $R/G$ must be trivial, which is a contradiction. Am I right?